# How to get updated variable by a python function from another python function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to access an updated initialized variable by a python method to another python method in same class. Below is my sample code block.

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = []

    def test1(self):
        self.a = [1,2,3,4,5]
        print ("Output of test1 #", self.a)

    def test2(self):
        print ("Output of test2 #",self.a)
test().test1()
test().test2()

Output # Output of test1 # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
         Output of test2 # []
```

My understanding is if i Initialize a variable in __ init __(self) section then i can update the same variable from a method in the class and access the same variable from another method of same class. Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: "access the same variable from another module of same class.". Do you mean "access the same variable from another *instance* of same class." Or am I misunderstanding what you mean.

Comment: Here, however, you're creating two *different* instances of `test`. Instead: `t = test(); t.test1(); t.test2()` does what you want. You may want up a bit more on [(Python) classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `module`, the word you want is `method`.

Your understanding is correct, but only for the same instance -- and you are creating two instances:

```
test().test1()
# ^- just created a new instance of test
test().test2()
# ^- just created another, different instance of test
```

What you want instead:

```
test_instance = test()
test_instance.test1()
test_instance.test2()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of test().test1() and test().test2() are two difference object. I think you should read more about Python OPP : https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html